# Torque+MAUI PBS submitted job strange startup

Tags: pbs, torque

I am using a Torque+MAUI cluster.

The cluster's utilization now is ~10 node/40 nodes available, a lot of job being queued but cannot be started.

I submitted the following PBS script using `qsub`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -o STDOUT
#PBS -e STDERR
#PBS -l walltime=500:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=32
#PBS -q zone0

cd /somedir/workdir/
java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m -jar client_1_05.jar
```

The job gets R(un) status immediately, but I had this abnormal information from `qstat -n`

```
8655.cluster.local      user       zone0    run.sh         --      1     32    --  500:00:00 R  00:00:31
z0-1/0+z0-1/1+z0-1/2+z0-1/3+z0-1/4+z0-1/5+z0-1/6+z0-1/7+z0-1/8+z0-1/9
+z0-1/10+z0-1/11+z0-1/12+z0-1/13+z0-1/14+z0-1/15+z0-1/16+z0-1/17+z0-1/18
+z0-1/19+z0-1/20+z0-1/21+z0-1/22+z0-1/23+z0-1/24+z0-1/25+z0-1/26+z0-1/27
+z0-1/28+z0-1/29+z0-1/30+z0-1/31
```

The abnormal part is `--` in `run.sh         --      1     32`, as the sessionId is missing, and evidently the script does not run at all, i.e. the java program does not ever had traces of being started.

After this kind of strange running for ~5 minutes, the job will be set back to Q(ueue) status and seemingly will not being run again (I had monitored this for ~1 week and it does not run even being queued to the top most job).

I tried submit the same job 14 times, and monitored its node in `qstat -n`, 7 copies ran successfully, having varied node numbers, but all jobs being allocated `z0-1/*` get stuck with this strange startup behavior.

1. Anyone know a solution to this issue?
2. For a temporary workaround, how can I specify NOT to use those strange nodes in PBS script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like something is wrong with those nodes. One solution would be to offline the nodes that aren't working: `pbsnodes -o <node name>` and allow the cluster to continue to work. You may need to release the holds on any jobs. I believe you can run `releasehold ALL` to accomplish this in Maui.

Once you take care of that I'd investigate the logs on those nodes (start with the pbs_mom logs and the syslogs) and figure out what is wrong with them. Once you figure out and correct what is wrong with them, you can put the nodes back online: `pbsnodes -c <node_name>`. You may also want to look into setting up some [node health scripts](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-2-8/help.htm#topics/11-troubleshooting/computeNodeHealthCheck.htm?Highlight=node%20health) to proactively detect and handle these situations.

Answer (score 0):

For users, contact your administrator and in the mean time, run the job using this workaround.

1. Use `pbsnodes` to check for free and healthy nodes
2. Modify PBS directive `#PBS -l nodes=<freenode1>:ppn=<ppn1>+<freenode2>:ppn=<ppn2>+...`
3. submit the job using `qsub`